# Find the average value of the function $F(x,y,z) = x^2y^2z^2$ along the curve.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

How do I find the average value of the function $F(x,y,z) = x^2y^2z^2$ along the curve given by

$$s(t) = \left( t,\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}t^2,\frac{t^3}{3} \right).$$

I understand that you need to find the arc length of $s(t)$, I know how to do that, but I can't think of how to go about this problem. Thanks.

The limits of $s(t)$ are $0$ to $3\sqrt 2$.

Comment: Integrate the function over the curve. Divide by the arclength of said curve.

Comment: @user127815 Why don't you use latex?

Answer (score 1):

Let's write down everything as a function of $t$:

$$ds=\sqrt{1+2t^2+t^4}dt=(t^2+1)dt \\ F(t)=(t)^2(\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}t^2)^2(\frac{t^3}{3})^2=\frac{t^{12}}{18}$$

And $\bar F$ would be:

$$\bar F=\frac {\int_{t=a}^b F(t)ds}{\int_{t=a}^bds}$$

Where $a$ and $b$ are the limits given in the question. If they are not given, then the result is obviously $\infty$.

Comment: The result is this not so useful formula:$(-a^{15}/270-a^{13}/234+b^{15}/270+b^{13}/234)/(-a^3/3-a+b^3/3+b)$

Comment: You could edit your answer and add that. That would be useful.

Comment: I know, but I was wondering that the final result is actually not worth putting into the answer.

Comment: Where did you get t^12/18? Its not t^3/3 + t?